# How do I add the VCL framework to an existing Delphi project (or know if it's been added)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, build-automation, finalbuilder

I'm running into problem using FinalBuilder 7 where some of my projects (converted from Delphi 7 to XE2 a few years ago) are failing to build because they can't find units in VCL namespaces (controls, spin, etc..)

When I click "Load Settings from Project File" in Final Builder, it takes out the default framework on the directories tab and sets it to none.  So then, I don't have VCL in my list of namespace prefixes.  I can the framework to VCL, but it still doesn't build unless I uncheck "Compiler" under Load Settings from project File.

I don't know how to see what the dcc32 is actually doing via finalbuilder (if someone can show me this, I can probably manage to fix the problem and answer my own question if it's too convoluted). But in any event, I can't tell you what the difference is between loading the settings from the project file and not doing so.

Unless it's some sort of bug, I think I could also fix this problem by adding the framework to the original project in Rad Studio (which is why the title of the question is what it is), but I don't know how to do that and I don't know whether or not it has been done, it's not asking me to add a framework any more and I don't remember if I did so in the first place, the files that are giving me grief are Windows Services and Console Applications.

---

I'd like to be able to use my Configurations/optionsets and dproj files to load Packages, Compiler Options, Linker options and Search Paths that the programmers set themselves, but manage output paths, conditional defines and version numbers in FinalBuilder.

---

**Follow Up**

Following [Robert Love's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18084189/1765) advice, I started monkeying with the base configuration.

Adding VCL and VCL.samples to the base configuration and then saving the dproj allowed me to compile in FinalBuilder, I had just had it in child configurations (probably because I had to add them later since they're Console and Service apps (but that could just be a coincidence)).

If I could still get the crux of this question (adding the VCL framework to an already converted project) I could more easily fix this problem uniformly in all my projects.  Does anyone know how to get to the framework chooser screen?

Answer (score 3):

I would open Delphi edit the Global Library path if only slightly and saving the changes.   This updates a 2nd storage area for the paths that is not always set correctly.

Then edit your Delphi Project and make sure the Base configuration path is same a the Global Settings, and that your release/debug are not overriding the base and removing the VCL Library Directories.

Then Retry in FinalBuilder

Comment: OK, I just tried the global library path thing you mentioned. It didn't compile in finalbuilder.  But you're right about the base configuration.  I added vcl and vcl.samples to the base configuration and now it does.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add the framework to an already existing project, you can use the Framework option on the Directories tab in FinalBuilder.

Sue

Comment: yeah, I saw that part, but only in finalbuilder, not in Rad Studio it doesn't have any permanent effect on the dproj

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Delphi has a habit of making a mess of the child configs with projects that are  upgraded. We see this a lot (in support requests), and unfortunately the best answer is to delete the dproj file and let delphi create a new one.. and then setup your configurations again.

I just spent 2 days doing this recently when we upgraded the Finalbuilder source from D2010 to XE2, it was painfully boring (70 projects in a group), but at least it works properly now.